# IdentityServer4 HTTPS/SSL on linux

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, https, ssl-certificate, identityserver4

I'm working on a [little dotnet + Angular project](https://github.com/Jin-K/Simple-CRM) where I use this kind of architecture: There are 3 separate folders:

- App (Angular Client)
- Auth (dotnet MVC with IdentityServer4)
- Api (dotnet MVC)

They should all work with https.

I was working on Windows until now, and I had no problem with SSL, certificates, etc. just using Visual Studio and IIS Express.

I was able at a moment to [deploy everything on docker using separate containers for each webservice (App, Auth, Api) and a "back-channel" network to allow containers to communicate](https://github.com/Jin-K/simple-crm/blob/dev/docker-compose.yml).
I did it binding some virtual volumes to the docker containers to let them use files that Visual Studio generated for me under:

- %USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets --> /root/.microsoft/usersecrets
- %USERPROFILE.aspnet\https --> /root/.aspnet/https/

I totally don't remember where I found those explanations to do it like that, but it worked !

Now, I'm on linux (Kali) and I'm not able at all to use self-signed certificates. I'm not a linux guy and I just don't get what I have to do to allow it to work.

I tried some things to create self-signed certificates in linux, but I always have the same issue when I try to go at https://localhost:44300 (app), https://localhost:44385 (api) or https://localhost:44321 (auth) ==> 
**NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**

- https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2018/07/self-signed-certificate-for-identity.html
- https://andrewlock.net/creating-and-trusting-a-self-signed-certificate-on-linux-for-use-in-kestrel-and-asp-net-core/
- https://askubuntu.com/a/94861

And each time I try a different manner to create a certificate and to trust it, I see that the problem is still present. But the strangest thing is that the creation date of the certificate doesn't change:

[image]

I would like at least to know where I can find that certificate on my machine (certificate of 6 october 2018 @ 17:28:09).

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the requirements to configure HTTPS/TLS for Angular and .NET applications. However I have experience with security and TLS in general.

When the browser (often Chrome) is throwing error `"NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"`, it means that the TLS server certificate is self-signed, therefore Chrome can't verify the server's identity using any of it's pre-trusted CA certificates.

**On Windows** is quite easy to 'solve' this problem by importing the server self-signed certificate in certmgr -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates folder.

I've never done this configuration **on Linux**, however I'm sure there is a similar approach. Firefox does not use the same pre-trusted CA certificates approach as Chrome, Firefox has it's own keystore, that is independent from the OS. Maybe these other questions can help you:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251811/install-root-ssl-certificate
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125731/install-ssl-certificate-in-iceweasel

*Note: Of course the correct setup would be to use a CA signed server certificate.*

Comment: ¡ Muchas gracias amigo ! Me pones luz en la oscuridad :D

Ok now I understeand why it worked with my docker containers. The host was a Windows so the certificates used in the containers were probably trusted in the "Trusted root Certification Authorities" of the Windows machine.
The question that I have now could sound stupid, but what is a "CA-signed server certificate" in a few words ? Can I generate one or should I pay a service to obtain one ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: The first phrase of the Wiki will help.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority